# Login form using vba

Tags: vba, forms, authentication

Im trying to create a login user form where the user would enter the username and password and hit login. The user will be prompted to change the password initially . Once the user changes the password, the new password will be saved in a sheet. What I want to achieve is that when the user opens the workbook next time it should not prompt for change password again.

```
Private sub workbook_open() 
  Userform1. Show
If userform1. Textbox1. Text = sheets('sheets2') . Range('a2'). Value then   
   If userform1. Textbox2. Text = sheets('sheets2'). Range('b2'). Value
      Then  userform2. Show
Endif
```

Userform2 is the change ur password form which i want to appear only once. When the user opens the workbook next time i only want the userid and password prompt. I don't want the user to be prompted with change password screen everytime. Can anyone help me please. Thanks.

Comment: What about writing some code to check for that additional requirement? Where exactly are you stuck in doing this?

Comment: Say for example you got locked out of your account and you get a temporary password. Once you login with the temporary password the next screen prompts you to change your password to something of your own choice. I'm stuck here, using userform2, users can change the password but the problem is that if they close the workbook and open it again.. The screen prompts them to put in their username and password and once they click on ok it again prompts them to change the password.. How can I stop triggering 'change your password' userform..

Comment: Use a boolean variable. If the user changed the password set the variable true or else false. When the user opens the workbook you can check the status of the variable. If false, open the form.

Comment: Thanks Zsmaster.. Will give it a shot..